# Wordpress Upgrade failed. Admin panel not working

Tags: wordpress, cpanel

I wanted to Upgrade the Wordpress installation, I clicked on the Upgrade to latest version link from my WP ADMIN panel and post that it has asked me to give FTP details for the Update for which FTP details were entered and Upgrade started. After few minutes I got Below ERROR and Now WP ADMIN is not loading. I tried to clear browser cache and cookies but still not working. Please Help in resolving the issue.

```
There has been a critical error on your website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions.

Learn more about debugging in WordPress.
```

I have further tried to debug and added below code in wp-config but i am not getting any errors on the page neither in the path /wp-content/debug.log file
 is there.

```
// Enable WP_DEBUG mode
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
// Enable Debug logging to the /wp-content/debug.log file
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
// Disable display of errors and warnings
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
@ini_set( 'display_errors', 0 );
// Use dev versions of core JS and CSS files (only needed if you are modifying these core files)
define( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG', true );
```

Comment: Try to rename the **plugin** directory and test the site is working or not. if not so revert back and upgrade it manually. before doing these stuff. please take a backup

Comment: Redo the installation manually by downloading the installation files from the site. This can sometimes happen is normal :) Remember before any upgrade you must make a backup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference : https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-upgrade-failed-wp-admin-panel-not-working/

Dear users, please use manual update if you can’t update automatically.

See here:

Updating WordPress

You can do it with cpanel:

1. Simple copy wp-content & wp-config.php to a directory out of public_html (for example, create a folder by name “backupold” and put files in it)
2. Download latest version
   https://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz
3. Upload it in your wordpress directory (output file will be in public_html/wordpress for example)
4. Copy (backuped contents) “wp-content” folder & “wp-config.php” file to “wordpress” folder & replace
5. Move all files and folders from “wordpress” folder to your site directory (by default, public_html) & replace.

Now enjoy!

Warning: do a backup before, and do as i say`enter code here`